# Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Hey I have a problem with importing vuetify into my project...

What am I doing wrong?

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

**app.js:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import store from "~/store";
import router from "~/router";

import App from "~/components/App";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
    store,
    router,
    Vuetify,
    ...App
});
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <loading ref="loading" />
    <router-view />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Loading from "./Loading";

export default {
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Loading
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**plugins/vuetify.js:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: "md" // 'mdi' || 'mdiSvg' || 'md' || 'fa' || 'fa4'
    },
    theme: {
        dark: false
    },
    themes: {
        light: {
            primary: "#4682b4",
            secondary: "#b0bec5",
            accent: "#8c9eff",
            error: "#b71c1c"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working somehow? I am having the same issue. Maybe you can provide the answer.

Answer (score 29):

Had the same issue which has bugged my head for like an hour now, how this worked I don't know either: but this is what I changed when importing vuetify in `vuetify.js`

changed:

`import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'`

replaced it with:

`import Vuetify from 'vuetify'`

Note: this could be a laravel issue only because the official vuetify documentation has the first form.

Comment: That seemed to help me. Additional issue for me: I had a given project which is built on BootstrapVue and now I wanted to incorporate Vuetify as well.

Comment: Not a laravel issue, I had this problem from a fresh CLI install. No idea why.

Comment: `In order to use treeshaking, you must import Vuetify from vuetify/lib.` This is not a permanent fix.

Comment: I originally had `import Vuetify from 'vuetify'`, but when I looked at how large our bundle size was I read [treeshaking](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#vuetify-loader), which said `In order to use treeshaking, you must import Vuetify from vuetify/lib.`

Answer (score 4):

got that project created with vue-cli v3? You either need to register components yourself or have a vuetify loader added, that parses your components and generates that list itself. the respective docu you can find here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte#vuetify-loader

Comment: project created with laravel

Answer (score 0):

To add Vuetify to existing project you should follow the below procedure

In your project folder run,

```
npm install vuetify --save
```

In your app.js

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
// To add vuetify css file
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({ ... })
```

To finish, you need to add a v-app component that wrap your entire application in order to make Vuetify works.

```
<v-app id="app">
  <router-view/>
</v-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    new Vue({
    store,
    router,
    Vuetify,
    ...App
});
```

To

```
    store,
    router,
    vuetify: Vuetify,
    ...App
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install Vuetify in your Project using "vue add vuetify" command

Step 2: In main.js write following code

import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'; //plugins folder installed when you add vuetify

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');

Step 3: Restart your Project because whenever you changed in main.js file then you need to restart your Project.

Answer (score 0):

Docs at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing/#testing-efficiency suggest to create an instance pass it to mount.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  vuetify = new Vuetify()
})

const wrapper = mount(CustomCard, {
  localVue,
  vuetify
})
```