# Vuetify component's not being registered

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have installed Vuetify as they recommend on their website and added it to my `app.js`.

```
require('./bootstrap');

import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

window.app = new Vue({
    vuetify,
    el: '#app',
    components: {

    },
    data: {

    },
    methods: {

    }
});
```

However i'm still getting errors when attempting to use the component's such as `v-switch` within the `app` element and also within other components.

**Error:**

```
Unknown custom element: <v-switch> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: @Still_learning Added to my question

Comment: This help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388315/unknown-custom-element-v-app-did-you-register-the-component-correctly-for

Comment: @Still_learning Ah yeah that did help actually, didn't expect such a simple answer

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388315/unknown-custom-element-v-app-did-you-register-the-component-correctly-for)